# What surrealistic 20s movie is mentioned in Woody Allen's Midnight in Paris

Tags: plot-explanation, midnight-in-paris

What surrealistic 20s movie is mentioned in Woody Allen's Midnight in Paris? It was something like a main character says to one of 3 surrealists (not Salvador Dalí but one of his collegaues) that he should make a movie about a group of people trying to exit a room.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the movie's [IMDb FAQ](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1605783/faq#.2.1.6):

> ***When Gil suggests to Bunuel a movie idea about people who can't leave a party, what is he talking about?***
>
> Gil's suggestion describes El angel exterminador (English title: The Exterminating Angel), a film made by Bunuel in 1962.

Here's The Exterminating Angel's [synopsis](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0056732/plotsummary):

> After a lavish dinner party, the guests find themselves mysteriously unable to leave the room... and over the next few days all the elaborate pretenses and facades that they've built up by virtue of their position in society collapse completely as they become reduced to living like animals...